# How to use select result as input for the second select (like foreach)?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is what I want to achieve, in pseudocode

```
part1 = select from foo ...
part2 = init empty
foreach row in part1
  part2 += select from foo where row.something as condition in here 
union part1, part2
```

Is it possible to do it in one query?

This is the structure

```
parent_name | name
------------+-------
null        | item1  # root
item1       | item2  # first level
item1       | item3  # first level
item2       | item4  # second level
item4       | item5  # third level
null        | item6  # another root
```

And the result - with condition that I want only tree where root name = item1

```
parent_name | name
------------+-------
null        | item1  
item1       | item2
item1       | item3  
item2       | item4
```

Basically it's a tree structure and I want to get all rows that are in the tree (two levels deep), starting with the root. Item5 is missing in the result because it's in the third level and item6 because it's different tree.

Comment: Yes it is called **correlated subquery**

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Maybe you're just after a join, rather than a correlated subquery? Without the information Gordon requested, it's difficult to guess what you mean.

Comment: @Boneist I added the example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you're after a hierarchical query:

```
with sample_data as (select null parent_name, 'item1' name from dual union all
                     select 'item1' parent_name, 'item2' name from dual union all
                     select 'item1' parent_name, 'item3' name from dual union all
                     select 'item2' parent_name, 'item4' name from dual union all
                     select 'item4' parent_name, 'item5' name from dual union all
                     select null parent_name, 'item6' name from dual)
select parent_name,
       name
from   (select parent_name,
               name,
               level lvl,
               max(level) over (partition by connect_by_root(name)) max_lvl
        from   sample_data sd
        connect by prior name = parent_name
                   and level <= 3
        start with parent_name is null)
where max_lvl > 1;

PARENT_NAME NAME 
----------- -----
            item1
item1       item2
item2       item4
item1       item3
```

N.B. I wasn't entirely sure why you didn't want to see item6 in the results, so I've assumed it was because it didn't have any child rows.

That's why I generated the "max_lvl" column, which simply finds the deepest level for that particular branch, and then added the outer query to filter out branches that only have the top level.

If that isn't the case, then you'll have to be much more specific in the logic behind why you don't want it in the results.

Comment: OP didn't want `item6` because  `I want only tree where root name = item1`. If you use `START WITH name = 'item1'` then you can simplify your query a lot.

Comment: yes, true; it's not immediately clear why the OP only wants item1 though, hence my query

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hierarchical query:

```
SELECT parent_name, NAME
FROM table1
WHERE LEVEL <= 3
CONNECT BY PRIOR NAME = parent_name
START WITH parent_name IS NULL;
ORDER BY 1 NULLS FIRST;
```

For me it is not clear why you don't want "item6" to be shown, that is not logical for me. Anyway, you achieve it by this:

```
SELECT parent_name, NAME
FROM table1
WHERE LEVEL <= 3
CONNECT BY PRIOR NAME = parent_name
START WITH NAME = 'item1'
ORDER BY 1 NULLS FIRST;
```

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/789ab/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( parent_name, name ) AS
          SELECT NULL,    'item1' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'item1', 'item2' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'item1', 'item3' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'item2', 'item4' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'item4', 'item5' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT NULL,    'item6' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   test
WHERE  LEVEL <= 3
START WITH name = 'item1'
CONNECT BY PRIOR name = parent_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/789ab/2/0)**:

```
| PARENT_NAME |  NAME |
|-------------|-------|
|      (null) | item1 |
|       item1 | item2 |
|       item2 | item4 |
|       item1 | item3 |
```